# Length of curve of intersection of two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given two surfaces $x^2 = 3y$ and $2xy=9z$, and I need to find the length of the curve of the intersection of those two surfaces from point $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,2)$, so I found a parametrization for that intersection and I know that formula for finding the length of curve in three dimensions, questions from what to what should I integrate?
I presume 0 to 3, because parametrization is $x=t, y=t^2/3, z=2/27t^3$ and if t=0 then it will be (0,0,0) and if t=3 then it will be (3,3,2). Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A parametrization of the intersection is given by

$$c(t)=(t, \frac{1}{3}t^2, \frac{2}{27}t^3)^T$$

fot $t \in [0,3]$.